# C++: initialize char array with a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Let's say I have a string called garbage.

Whatever's in garbage, I want to make a char array out of it. Each element would be one char of the string.

So, code would be similar to:

```
const int arrSize = sizeof(garbage); //garbage is a string
char arr[arrSize] = {garbage};
```

But, this will give an error "cannot convert string to char in initialization".

What is the correct way to do this? I just want to feed the darn thing a string and make an array out of it.

Comment: Assuming by string, you mean `std::string`, `sizeof(garbage)` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  It just gives you the size of a `std::string` object, which is a compile time constant that has no relation to the length of the string, which is a runtime value.

Comment: You are correct, Ben. sizeof(garbage) does not give me what I want. Good catch! garbage.size() is the correct method.

Comment: Yes, but then `arrSize` cannot be used to specify the size of `arr`, because it would no longer be a compile time constant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++ `std::string` maintains an internal `char` array. You can access it with the `c_str()` member function.

```
#include <string>
std::string myStr = "Strings! Strings everywhere!";
const char* myCharArr = myStr.c_str();
```

Keep in mind that you cannot modify the internal array. If you want to do so, make a copy of the array and modify the copy.

Comment: why a std::string would need to be converted to a char* is beyond me, but a good answer to this question.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. And to answer the question above, I'm implementing a string randomizer. I figure I can randomize to get a number in the range of the string size, and then pull a char from the string. Might be good for password generation if I have the entire alphanumeric set as the string.

Comment: You could do what you want without getting the array - `myStr.size()` will return the string's length, and you can access any character in the string at index `i` with `myStr[i]`.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're after is a lot simpler:

```
char arr[] = "some interesting data (garbage)";
```

Comment: Thank you, This answered the reason I came to this question. 

I am trying to convert a piece of C code to C++. In the C code, it declares a 'char * foo = "string literal" ', and foo is expected to be a char *, not a const char *, in  a later function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `garbage.data()`, which is already a pointer to the first element of an array of chars containing your string data.

Comment: I don't think the initialization would work, since `arr` is not const.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, of course, but I wouldn't even initialize anything. Just use the data directly. If you need a copy, copy the string.

Answer (score -1):

Or here is a heavy way to do so.

```
#include <string>
std::string temp = "something";
char* myChar = new char(temp.length());
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); ++i){
    a[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: Kind reminder: remember to delete "a" after finished using it.